# How to open MS Office docs with Google Drive by default?

Tags: google-drive, microsoft-office

I don't have MS Office installed so it's pretty annoying to have to upload the file to Google Drive every time I need to open one.

Is it possible to set up Google Drive to open my `.docx`, `.pptx`, etc., files by default, as for Google Docs files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Install openoffice.org
2. Install http://www.gdocsopen.com/
3. https://www.insynchq.com/

Comment: second option was the easiest.

Answer (score -1):

Download and install Google Drive for PC/MAC. Your drive files will sync to your desktop where those program defaults will supersede. I.E. `xlxs` files will open in Excel, `docx` will open in Word etc.

Comment: The OP clearly states that “I don't have MS Office installed”, so your solution does not apply.